# Open and Run Python file after cloning from Github

Tags: github, google-colaboratory, clone

I have made a clone of a repository of Github in Google Colab. It is done successfully and I can see the files there. After cloning when I tried to open the individual file of python I was unable to open the individual file.
Kindly guide me on how to work on individual files after creating a clone as we open them as a normal file directly from the link of GitHub in collab.
Thanks